# Old session not being destroyed when logging in with new user

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

**Security will be added later**

I have a login script that either returns a message in json (wrong combo, empty fields etc) or starts a session and redirects a user according to what user logged in.

There are 2 possibilities now: `admin` and `user`.

When I first login as admin everything works fine, but then I login as a user, and I see the name of the admin and the logo that is in the admin session. I am redirected to the correct page however.

No matter how much I refresh (even hard refresh ctrl + shift + r) I can't get the correct user information to be displayed, only if I start an incognito window in Chrome and login as a user first.

Sometimes when I login I also get immediately redirected to my login form. So something is definately wrong in my code but I am not sure what.

My PHP script that is called by ajax code and starts the session is returned as `JSON` is it even possible to start a session when that is the case?

My ajax code now:

```
// Login Ajax Code
$( "#content" ).on("submit", "#loginform", function( event ) {
  // Stop normal form behaviour
  event.preventDefault();
  // Retrieve input fields and their values
  var $form = $( this ),
  $username = $form.find( "input[name='username']" ).val(),
  $userpassword = $form.find( "input[name='userpassword']" ).val(),
  url = $form.attr( "action" );
  // Post above values to the action of the form
  var posting = $.post( url, { username: $username, userpassword: $userpassword} );
  // Show result in a div
  posting.done(function( data ) {
    obj = JSON.parse(data);
    if(obj.userdata == ''){
      $( "#loginresult" ).empty().slideDown('fast').append( obj.message );
    }else if(obj.userdata == 'admin'){
      window.location.href = "http://www.vcaweb.nl/admin";
    }else if(obj.userdata == 'user'){
      window.location.href = "http://www.vcaweb.nl/dashboard";
    }
  }, "json");
});
```

My php script:

```
<?php
session_start();

*connection class is here*
$conn = new Connection;

$username = $_POST['username'];
$userpassword = $_POST['userpassword'];

*error messages code not relevant*
else{
  //Both filled in, begin logincode:
  $getuser = "
    SELECT u.id as userid, u.username, u.rights, u.password, c.name, c.userid as companyuid, c.logo
    FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN company c
    ON u.id = c.userid
    WHERE u.username = '".$conn->real_escape_string($username)."'";
  $getusercon = $conn->query($getuser);
  $getuser = $getusercon->fetch_assoc();

    if(!empty($getuser['logo'])){
      $sessionlogo = str_replace('/home/vcaweb/public_html/', '', $getuser['logo']);
    }else{
        $sessionlogo = 'Hier een placeholder';
    }

  if($userpassword == $getuser['password']){
    if($getuser['rights'] == '1'){
      $_SESSION['userdata']['user'] = 'Mark Kraaijo';
            $_SESSION['userdata']['rights'] = '1';
            $_SESSION['userdata']['logo'] = 'assets/images/logo.png';
      $loginresult = array(
        'login_result' => 'success',
     );
      $logindata = array(
        'userdata' => 'admin',
     );
    echo json_encode($logindata);
    }else{
      $_SESSION['userdata']['user'] = $getuser['name'];
            $_SESSION['userdata']['rights'] = '0';
            $_SESSION['userdata']['logo'] = $sessionlogo;
      $loginresult = array(
        'login_result' => 'success',
     );
      $logindata = array(
        'userdata' => 'user',
     );
    echo json_encode($logindata);
    }
  }else{
        $logindata = array(
            'userdata' => '',
            'message' => 'Wachtwoord en gebruikersnaam komen niet overeen',
     );
    echo json_encode($logindata);
  }
}
?>
```

In my header of my redirected pages I have the following:

```
// Check if session is set
if(isset($_SESSION['userdata'])){
  // Check if user is admin, if yes and user has rights to visit page, redirect to loginpage
  if($_SESSION['userdata']['rights'] == '0' && $restriction == 'admin'){
    header('Location: http://www.vcaweb.nl/login');
  }
  // Logo
  $logo = '<img class="headerlogo" src="'.$_SESSION['userdata']['logo'].'">';
}else{
  header('Location: http://www.vcaweb.nl/login');
}
```

And in the header of my login form I have (including my connection class file which starts the session):

```
session_unset();
session_destroy();
```

Why is the session not destroyed entirely?

Comment: **Warning: Never store passwords in clear text.** Use PHP's `password_hash()` to create a hash of the password (which is what you store) and `password_verify()` to verify the password. You should also look into using Prepared Statements instead of manually escaping user input and building your query manually.

Comment: I know, I should have added that I will add security later. @MagnusEriksson It's just the testing phase at the moment.

Comment: _"I will add security later"_ - The famous last words right before your site's getting breached. _Suggestion:_ Never think "I'll do that later" when talking about security. You will eventually forget/miss to fix some crucial parts. Also, when you add security, you will modify the above code, changing the flow and might introduce new bugs/fix the current ones. So debugging code that you knowingly are going to change doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Cleaner way to clear a current session is to use `$_SESSION = [];`.

Comment: If you have `session_destroy()` before this script, this sentence might shed some light: _"It does not unset any of the global variables associated with the session, or unset the session cookie. To use the session variables again, session_start() has to be called."_. Try and unset the session as @IncredibleHat suggests or like the answer below and check if it works better.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your user session with `unset($_SESSION['userdata']);` and use `session_regenerate_id(true)` right after `session_start()`

Using `session_destroy()` function is right, but the `session_unset()` is used for deprecated ways to create a session.

Please follow this link for more informations http://php.net/manual/ro/function.session-destroy.php